# How to get any columns of a rank N tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

Consider the tensor

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([
    [[111, 112], [121, 122]],
    [[211, 212], [221, 222]],
])

>>> print(array[:, 0, [0, 1]])
[
 [111 112]
 [211 212]
]

>>> print(array[:, 1, [0, 1]])
[
 [121 122]
 [221 222]
]
```

Now, how would I get the elements `(:, 0, 1)`, and `(:, 1, 0)`,

```
[
 [112 121]
 [212 221]
]
```

as a numpy ndarray as above?

It seems that

```
>>> print(array[:, [(1, 0), (0, 1)]])
```

is not the correct notation.

Generally, given a list of tuples of indexes, how do I get an N-1 tensor of those tuples (-1 because the first rank is always `:` here)?

If numpy does not support it, I am willing to use a library other than numpy to do this.

Comment: I think you're confusing `rank` with `way` or `order`. Rank has a completely different meaning in tensor decomposition. In your example, you have a 3-way tensor or sometimes called 3-order tensor and you'd like to get a matrix (a 2-way tensor or just 2D array) from it.

Comment: [Am I](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorRank.html) @kmario23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[:, [0,1], [1,0]]`, see more about the syntax [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
array[:, [0,1], [1,0]]
#array([[112, 121],
#       [212, 221]])
```

Comment: Impressive. I tried with `np.transpose` but couldn't get any result.